# What's wrong with this code that attempts to listen repeatedly on a socket?

Tags: c, sockets

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <netdb.h>
#include <netinet/in.h>
#include <sys/socket.h>
#include <sys/types.h>
#include <pthread.h>
#include <arpa/inet.h>

struct sockaddr_in server, acc;
int sock;

int stuff(void) {
    char buffer[2000];

    recv(sock, buffer, sizeof(buffer), 0);
    send(sock, "HTTP/1.1 200 OK\nContent-Type: text/html\n\nHello", sizeof("HTTP/1.1 200 OK\nContent-Type: text/html\n\nHello"), 0);

    shutdown(sock, SHUT_RDWR);
    
    return 0;
}

int main(void) {
    int size;

    sock = socket(AF_INET, SOCK_STREAM, 0);

    server.sin_family      = AF_INET;
    server.sin_addr.s_addr = INADDR_ANY;
    server.sin_port        = htons(1111);

    if (bind(sock, (struct sockaddr*)&server, sizeof(server)) == -1) {
        perror("Error:");
        return 1;
    }

    while (1) {
        listen(sock, 5);
        sock = accept(sock, (struct sockaddr*)&acc, &size);
        printf("accepted\n");

        stuff();

        close(sock);
    }
}
```

This is meant to be an extremely basic HTTP server.
I don't know what's going wrong, but the connection seems to not end with the client.
Opening this in the browser, it doesn't stop loading and the console is flooded with "accepted" (line 42). No new connections can be accepted.

Comment: After the first time, you're calling accept on a closed socket over and over. It returns an error saying the socket is closed, but your program doesn't care and keeps looping

Comment: Is this also caused by shutdownl?

Comment: it's caused by your program closing a socket and then trying to accept a connection from the socket it just closed (which wasn't one that could accept connections, anyway)

Comment: I removed close() and it still seems to be having the same issue. Sorry, I'm fairly new to socket programming 

Comment: Are you new to programming?

Comment: Have been learning for a few years loll

Comment: You are missing the fact that accept returns a new socket.

Comment: Also you should not call `listen()` in a loop every time. One call after `bind()` is enough.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

After your program accepts a connection, it forgets about the socket that listens for new connections, does remember the newly connected socket, does some stuff with that socket, closes it, then tries to accept another connection from the *connected* socket *that it just closed.*

There are two problems here:

- It's the wrong socket
- Even if it was the right socket, it's closed

You create socket number 3 (for example) to wait for new connections. You wait for a connection on socket 3 and the new connection is socket number 4 (for example). Then you do the stuff, then you close socket 4, then you wait for a new connection on socket 4. Do you see the mistake here? Socket 3 is the one that accepts connections.

Since you are not new to programming, you should be able to figure out how to make your program call `accept` with the right socket.